# How can I extract a Debian binary package from the ISO of an installation disk?

Tags: debian, iso, deb

What process do I use to extract a Debian binary package from a Debian/Ubuntu based distribution's ISO image?

Comment: Improvement in question will be appreciated.

Comment: Is you question “how do I copy a `.deb` file from an `iso` image?”?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, It is possible to get/extract [deb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_%28file_format%29) directly from distro's iso image (ISO of an installation disk). Follow the steps to accomplish this:-

1. **Mounting iso (live cd version) as virtual system (root`/`):**

   - mount iso to `/media/cdrom`

     ```
     sudo mkdir /media/cdrom
     sudo mount -o loop /path/to/iso /media/cdrom
     ```
   - mount [`filesystem.squashfs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS) to `/mnt`:

     ```
     sudo mount -o loop /media/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs /mnt
     ```

   Now virtual system from iso image is mounted (as read only) and rooted on `/mnt`
2. **Get required deb(s) by `dpkg-repack` command:-**

   Suppose I want to get package `foo` from recently mounted system then run:

   ```
   dpkg-repack --root=/mnt foo
   ```

   In which `--root=/mnt` says system is rooted on `/mnt`

   ```
   --root=dir
             Take package from filesystem rooted on <dir>. This is useful if, for example, you have another computer
             nfs mounted on /mnt, then you can use --root=/mnt to reassemble packages from that computer.
   ```

---

**Example of Utilization:-**

Suppose I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I've iso images of Xubuntu, Kubuntu etc then I can get xfce or kde applications (that are pre-installed in accordingly derivative) directly from iso. Also I can get whole desktop environment like `xubuntu-desktop` from Xubuntu's iso image!

Another example: Trisquel 7.0 LTS is derivative of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS which is [completely free](http://www.gnu.org/distros/free-distros.html) distro with some helful packages pre-installed like `gimp`. If you have iso image of Trisquel then you can get `gimp` directly from iso image and can install in Ubuntu!

Important notes that may helpful how to get required debs (example of getting `gimp` from iso):-

- Use `sudo apt-get install -s gimp | grep Inst | awk '{print $2}' > pkgreq` **to list** required packages
- And finally run `cat pkgreq | xargs sudo dpkg-repack --root=/mnt` **to get** those deb(s)!

---

**Note:-** This will helps successfully on Same version of derivatives and distribution (like Trisquel 7.0 and Ubuntu 14.04, same version of Ubuntu’s derivative like xfce,kde etc), for different version and/or derivative there may/must dependency issue have to be solved.

Comment: I recommend apt offline repository method to install package form deb(s) for offline installation

Answer (score 0):

The server version of Ubuntu includes the .deb packages in the iso. The Desktop and Server version differ basically in the installation method but the packages, as far as I know, are essentially the same so, another option is: download de file iso of the Server version of the corresponding Ubuntu version.

Then, just mount the iso file (with the -o loop option), and you will find the '.deb'  packages inside the 'pool/main' folder.

As Ubuntu derivate from Debian you can do the same for Debian. You will find the packages in the same place.